# Trying to combine React Contexts

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm trying to combine Contexts by creating 'with' functions for each Context, then use `compose` function to combine them into `withProviders` function, which wraps App component. But it doesn't work, state doesn't change. So, what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the example on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/pedantic-fast-717xb9

main.jsx

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

App.jsx

```js
import { useAuth, withProviders } from "./withProviders";

function App() {
  const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useAuth();
  const toggle = () => setAuthenticated((b) => !b);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>{authenticated.toString()}</div>
      <button onClick={toggle}>toggle</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default withProviders(App);
```

withProviders.jsx

```js
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";
import compose from "compose-function";

const AuthContext = createContext([false, () => null]);

const withAuth = (component) => {
  return function AuthProvider() {
    const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(false);
    return (
      <AuthContext.Provider value={[authenticated, setAuthenticated]}>
        {component()}
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
  };
};

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);

export const withProviders = compose(withAuth);
```

Comment: What does `compose` do?

Comment: @ChrisHamilton, `compose(f, g, h) = (...args) => f(g(h(...args)))`. `compose` can be removed in this example and `App` can be wrapped with `withAuth` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/morning-lake-7hj8mg

Calling component as a function doesn't work properly with hooks
Use way I provided or `React.createElement(component)`